# Pass by reference with strings

Tags: c, pointers, memory, pass-by-reference

So I'm writing a string fragment reassembly program and am having trouble with the following. If one string is contained in the other, I need to have the first String be set to the larger of the two strings (this is key when I merge the two strings together). However, my pass by reference keeps messing up for some reason and the strings never get reassigned, therefore the merging messes up.

Here is the pass by reference:

```
int oneRound(char*frags[], int* numFrags) {
    int currMax = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int mergeOne = 0;
    int mergeTwo = 0;
    char *fragOne;
    char *fragTwo;
    for(int i = 0; i < *numFrags; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < *numFrags; j++) {
                    fragOne = frags[i];
                    fragTwo = frags[j];
                    currMax = FindMaxOverlap(&fragOne, &fragTwo);
                    if (currMax >= max) {
                            max = currMax;
                            mergeOne = i;
                            mergeTwo = j;
                    }
            }
    }
```

Here is the function it gets called under :

```
int FindMaxOverlap(char**firstString, char**secondString)
      if (strstr(*firstString, *secondString) != NULL || strstr(*secondString, *firstString) != NULL) {
            maxOverlap = length;
            if (strlen(*firstString) < strlen(*secondString)) {
                    char *temp = *firstString;
                    *firstString = *secondString;
                    *secondString = temp;
            }
    }
```

Comment: How do you declare `fragOne` and `fragTwo`?

Comment: So far I can't see a problem here. It must be outside of the presented code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: added more context

Comment: can you give an example of a pair of strings for which it fails ?

Comment: You might want to use a small set of input that you know to create the wrong result, and then use a debugger to step through the code, possibly line by line, to see that everything is correct.

Comment: I hope thats not your complete `FindMaxOverlap` function because you've said it will return an `int` and I can't see you handle that part in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is changing the (temporary) variables `fragOne` and `fragTwo`:

```
fragOne = frags[i];
fragTwo = frags[j];
currMax = FindMaxOverlap(&fragOne, &fragTwo);
```

it is not modifying the elements of the array `frags`, which I believe is the intended behaviour. Pass the address of the array elements to achieve the reassigment:

```
currMax = FindMaxOverlap(&frags[i], &frags[j]);
```

Additionally, as pointed out by [Jite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/921723/jite) in the comments, `FindMaxOverlap()` must return an `int` otherwise the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Nice catch there. These kind of bugs are so easy to miss at a quick glance :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stepping through your code with [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)? I don't know what compiler you're using, but with gcc, you can compile your code using gcc with the -g switch:

```
$ gcc -g maxover.c -o max
```

and then you can step through it with gdb:

```
 gdb max.out
```

Love your debugger :)